# How do I get a handle to a dynamically-generated field name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, field

I have a series of fields created dynamically based on database records. They will be named cardObject1, cardObject2, and so on for as many rows as necessary. I'm now trying to access a specific cardObject field in a function where the number is passed in, but am getting an error message.

The field looks like this:

```
<input name="cardObject241" value="2,$25.00,1" type="hidden">
```

The js code I'm using looks like this:

```
function deleteFromCart(id){
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item from your cart?")){
    var voucherNbr = document.getElementById("voucherNbr").value;
    var cardObjectArray = document.getElementById("cardObject"+id).value.split();
    var amtToDelete = cardObjectArray[1];
    alert("need to delete " + amtToDelete); 
  }
```

}

And the error I'm getting is

```
document.getElementById("cardObject" + id) is null
```

on this line:

```
 var cardObjectArray = document.getElementById("cardObject"+id).value.split();
```

How can I get a handle to the cardObject field that ends with the number passed in as the id param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an id="" attribute with the same name as the name attribute.

```
<input id="cardObject241" name="cardObject241" value="2,$25.00,1" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your input field needs an id as well as a name, so it would look like this:

```
<input name="cardObject241" id="cardObject241" value="2,$25.00,1" type="hidden">
```

Secondly, if you have an object that may or may not exist, it's always a good idea to check for existence before you start manipulating properties:

```
var tempObj=document.getElementById("cardObject"+id)
if(tempObj) {
    var cardObjectArray = tempObj.value.split();
    ...do your stuff with cardObjectArray....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByName()` or (cross-browser back to the Stone Age)

```
document.forms[formIndexOrName].elements["cardObject" + id].value.split(",")
```

Comment: Stan, is that you? Domino stan? Hi! It's Esther Strom, former Domino dev. I haven't really been following Lotus blogs recently, but I'm glad to see you're still around!

Comment: Yep, that's I. Still alive, but the kicking's mostly involuntary these days. Can't do much but answer the few questions I can still figure out these days (and I've only updated the blog a couple of times a year for the past few years). It's good to see you're still around too -- last I remember there was a bit of a health scare.